# Validators in DetailsView insert mode

Tags: asp.net, crud, web2py

I have changed the DefaultMode property of my details view to Insert since I wanted to create default insert form for my sql server table. Now I wish to add the validators, like RequiredFieldValidator,RegularExpressionValidator etc.

So is that possible? If not, then is there a shortcut way to create an Insert form for a database table in Asp.net like SQLFORM in python framework web2py([refer here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#SQLFORM))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all `boundfields` to `TemplateField`, open `EditItemTemplate` of each `TemplateField` to add `validation` controls.

Comment: Thanks AVD! that solved the issue.But what about SQLFORM like alternative in Asp.net?